# TFS migration via OpsHub - very slow

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am testing a TFS2013 (source control only) migration to VSO via OpsHub (1.1.0.005).

I chose a Team Project that has 2500 changesets, but when migrating, the OpsHub UI displays [iterating value]/32894 Changeset(s)/Labels passed.

I have not looked to see how many labels exist, but I doubt there are 30,000+.

The migration process has been running for 5 hours, and looks like it may run for 3 or 4 days.

Is this really how long it takes to migrate a small Team Project?

Answer (score 0):

The 30k Labels would be those that exist at the Collection Level scope. Since, the utility migrates TFS Build Labels (which TFS automatically creates at the collection level scope). However, the labels which are not pertaining to the project(s) that have been selected to be migrated will NOT be migrated. Yet they will have to be preprocessed to decide if they are of the relevant project or not.

Hence you will see the total count as an aggregation, but the processing+migration will only be done for relevant labels. And the iteration over unneeded labels will be done with in seconds.

On a side note, what is the rough size of the project that is being migrated?

Comment: what is the rough size of the project that is being migrated: 60 megabytes

Comment: Sorry. 60 MB? As per the latest revision, the size on disk for the project is 60 MB? That seems strange. What is the current status of your migration?