# TFS migration from TFS backup to VS Online using Opshub is extremely slow

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

We are performing a migration from a backup of a hosted TFS instance to VS Online. The main issue is that the migration is very, very slow. Here are the details:

The backup is on an Azure VM and the migration tool is running from a second VM in the same location (same network even). The migration tool is reading directly from TFS and inserting into VS Online.

Both work items and version control is being migrated. 
There are 88819 revisions for the work items.

On average the migration tool does one revision every 6 seconds (averaged over time period).

- [Link to screenshot of tool after having run for 50 hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqd9O.png)

According to these posts, the speed issues should be resolved, but not in this case.

[Visual Studio Online migration utility very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779629/visual-studio-online-migration-utility-very-slow)

[Slow TFS migration from on-premise to TFS online with OpsHub tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237777/slow-tfs-migration-from-on-premise-to-tfs-online-with-opshub-tool)

[TFS migration via OpsHub - very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597420/tfs-migration-via-opshub-very-slow)

Opshub version 1.3.0.000.
We have tried increasing the VM size/specs, but it doesn't make any difference.
With the current speed we are looking at a 6-7 day migration cycle for a relatively small repository. We might have to do this 3-4 times for testing purposes, which means almost a month used migrating!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, The other threads are referring to Source Control migration performance improvement. For WIT migration our average time noted at client ends it about 4-5 Seconds per revision. But, this is ofcourse dependent on the data in question. Because, file attachments are a part of the revision and their size does matter for upload.

Comment: On a side note, I think you should know that the utility is designed such that it can run in background, meaning that you can continue using your TFS on-prem whilst the migration is running.